# Fitting a curve using matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, curve-fitting

I have a plot with two intersecting parabolas. Is there a way that I can detect the two correctly and fit two parabolas, one through each of them? My current code fits only a single parabola:

```
x=-100:1:100;
y=(x.^2)/(4);
x1=-50:1:150;
y1=(x.^2)/(4);
x=[x,x1];
y=[y,y1];
f = fittype('((x)*(x))/4*p',...
'dependent',{'y'},'independent',{'x'},...
'coefficients',{'p'})
fit1= fit(x',y',f)
plot(fit1,x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: The curves are so regular that one wonders if you can't tell beforehand to which parabola the points belong, or even if you need to fit the parabolas at all...

Comment: I think what you want is to first find the two minimums/local minimums of the parabolas, and then the intersection of the two parabolas, and use fit on only a section of each parabola instead of the whole thing. This should not be a difficult problem.

Comment: to improve @GameOfThrows 'comment I offer start from local minimums checking closest points and sort them by two arrays. The only problem will be in the interceptions, but we also can check derivative which must changes slowly

Comment: You can consider using RANSAC to fit one parabola while excluding the other. Here is a tutorial about [outlier removal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/removing-outliers.html#bt1uahi-1), and [read about RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC).

Comment: I was thinking of Ransac too but it allows us to fit lines do you have an example to fit curves?

Comment: This is going to sound clumsy, but it might be simplest, if not fastest, to use a tool like http://www.datathief.org/  to extract the two sets of data by eye, and then process each one separately.  In general, it's very difficult to fit a curve to a dataset that is not 1:1 -- i.e. you have multiple `y` values for each `x` value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions I was able to write a code that runs ransac for curves

```
function [f1] = Ransac(x,y)
voting=[0,0,0,0];
for i=1:10000

[y1,idx] = datasample(y,5);
x1=x(idx);
p = polyfit(x1,y1,2);
f1 = polyval(p,x);
error=(((f1-y).^2));
error(error>100)=0;
indx =find(ismember(voting(:,1:3),'rows'),1);
if (isempty(indx)==1)
    voting=[voting;[p,sum(error)]];
else
    voting(indx,4) =   voting(indx,4)+sum(error);
end
end
[s,t]=max(voting(:,4));
p=voting(t,1:3);
f1 = polyval(p,x);
end
```